# How to save value in List View only once?

Tags: android, database, firebase

I'm trying to make an Android application using Firebase.
In the application, I have given the feature of controlling output devices on the basis of the sensor value.
For example, if the value of the light intensity (from LDR sensor) is greater than entered value by the user the LED will be HIGH. And I'm also saving these values in another activity using database class.

I'm able to do all of this but the data in ListView is getting added multiple times.

I think that this piece of code is giving an error

```java
if(analogvalue < value){
    mDatabaseHelper.addData(status);
    if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
    else{Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}
    if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
    else{Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}
}

confirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Get your custom_toast.xml layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

        //Initializing the text views
        EditText editText =  findViewById(R.id.link2);
        final String link2 = editText.getText().toString();

        EditText editText1 =  findViewById(R.id.idvalue);
        final String StringValue = editText1.getText().toString();


        //Adding functionality to the text views
        fire2 = new Firebase("https://iotsense.firebaseio.com/");
        Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("S1");
        fireChild.setValue("4");

        // Read from the database
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.

                if(StringValue.length()>0 && link2.length()>0) {

                    try{ status = dataSnapshot.child("Analog").getValue().toString();}
                    catch (NullPointerException ignored){

                    }
                    if(status==null){
                        TextView text4 = layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                        text4.setText(" Error: Wrong ID. ");
                        // Toast...
                        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 540);
                        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setView(layout);
                        toast.show();
                        return;
                    }
                    else{ 
                        analogvalue = Integer.parseInt(status);
                        pin.setText(status);

                        mDatabaseHelper.addData(status);

                        final int value = Integer.parseInt(StringValue);
                        if (analogvalue >= value) {

                            Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin1");
                            fireChild.setValue(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            Firebase fireChild1 = fire2.child("Pin2");
                            fireChild1.setValue(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        }

                        if(analogvalue < value){

                            if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
                            else{Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}
                            if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
                            else{Firebase fireChild = fire2.child("Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                // Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

In database, the values are getting added multiple times.
I think if I can use the non-selected value of spinner then the `if(analogvalue < value)` loop will not run multiple times.

[image: This is how the screen looks like]

Comment: as a side note, you should never do this : `catch (NullPointerException ignored){ }`

Comment: Paste complete class to give a better idea.